# How to Round Decimal Types

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to round decimal types in a pandas dataframe and keep getting the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

I have tried numerous variations of the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

data = pd.DataFrame({"Rate" : [25.25,30.12,35.3,40.12,45.31]})
data['Rate'] = data['Rate'].apply(Decimal)
data['New_Rate']=(data['Rate'] * Decimal(.02)) + data['Rate']
data['Round_Rate']=round(data['New_Rate'],2)
```

Comment: `Decimal(.02)` is actually `Decimal('0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875')`, the exact representation of the `float` literal `.02`.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: I am working with $ and need accuracy to they penny. So, to answer your question, I don't necessarily need/want .0200000..... but I cannot perform the operation without converting it to decimal, right?